# I am getting a strange install screen on Kali Linux and when I install all the way,I get a blue screen?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

[image: Strange install screen here]

I have a picture of the issue here.  The screen than proceeds to turn blue?  Any help????

Comment: It turns blue and stays that way after you select a language by pressing enter?

Comment: Yes that is what happens.

Answer (score -2):

You can try verifying the checksum. This ensures that the .iso you have is not corrupted. You can do that here: onlinemd5.com. Blue screens can also be a sign of hardware failure. Ensure that all of your hardware is compatible with the OS.

Comment: I wouldn't trust a site with that. You can easily get md5 value with your Linux, and download MD5 that you should make check against from your ISO file provider(probably distro creators).

Comment: Yes the Kali Linux providers do give out a SHA1 hash. However, I offered the site since it is user friendly and if he doesn't have another Linux system. Then he has to go and install different software to get the checksum.

Comment: He could also use live installation medium to verify the integration of the ISO. I may sound paranoid, but the site could be lying or compromised, thus not trustworthy; although this is unlikely and he'll probably be fine.